# Double integration including e?

Tags: integration

I would like to calculate the following expression:

$\iint_D x^2e^\sqrt{x^2+y^2} dxdy$

for D = ${ a^2\le x^2+y^2 \le b^2} $ and $ 0 \le a \le b$

How would you do it, in a step-by-step, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\iint_D x^2e^\sqrt{x^2+y^2} dxdy=\iint_D (rcos\phi)^2e^r\cdot r drd\phi= \iint_D r^3cos^2\phi e^r drd\phi=$$
$$=\int^{2\pi}_0d\phi \int^b_a r^3cos^2\phi e^r dr=\int^{2\pi}_0cos^2\phi d\phi \int^b_a r^3 e^r dr=$$
$$=\int^{2\pi}_0cos^2\phi d\phi ( r^3-3r^2+6r-6) e^r|^b_a =\int^{2\pi}_0(( b^3-3b^2+6b-6) e^b-(a^3-3a^2+6a-6) e^a) cos^2\phi d\phi= $$
$$=(( b^3-3b^2+6b-6) e^b-(a^3-3a^2+6a-6) e^a)\int^{2\pi}_0 cos^2\phi d\phi $$
$$=(( b^3-3b^2+6b-6) e^b-(a^3-3a^2+6a-6) e^a)(\frac{1}{2}\phi +\frac{1}{4}sin2\phi)|^{2\pi}_0= $$
$$=(( b^3-3b^2+6b-6) e^b-(a^3-3a^2+6a-6) e^a)\pi $$

Comment: Interesting and straighforward.

Answer (score 1):

Use polar coordinate

$$dxdy=rdr d\theta$$
$$r:a \to b$$
$$\theta:0 \to 2 \pi$$

$$\iint_D x^2e^\sqrt{x^2+y^2} dxdy=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{a}^{b}r^2\cos^2\theta e^rrdr d\theta=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^2\theta d\theta \int_{a}^{b}e^rr^3dr$$
These are the basic integration.

Comment: Would you decide to continue as the other poster (aid78) or choose another route @maneesh ?

Comment: I don't understand. May I know, what do you mean @Terry

Comment: If you would continue to calculate, how would you do? @maneesh